# How to find the value of $g'(2)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

If we have
$$
\lim_{x\to1} \cfrac{f(x)-f(1)}{x^2-1} = 4\;, 
\quad 
g(x)+g(2)=2\; 
\quad \text{and } \quad
(f \circ g)'(2) = 8, 
$$
what is the value of $g'(2)$?

To solve the problem I rewrote the limit as
$$
\lim_{x\to1} \cfrac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1} \times \cfrac{1}{x+1} = \cfrac{f'(1)}{2} = 4 
$$
so $f'(1)=8$. And we have $(f \circ g)'(2) = g'(2) \times f'(g(2)) = 8$. So in order to solving the problem I need to find $f'(g(2))$. I don't know how to do it. and also how can I use $g(x)+g(2)=2$?

Comment: If $g(x) + g(2) = 2$ over (apparently) the entire domain, doesn't that make $g'(x) =0$ throughout? That doesn't cohere with the rest though.

Comment: This is what happens when one tries to design a complicated question. It would have been better had the question just said $g(2)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $g(2)+g(2)=2$ and therefore $g(2)=?$
However as $g$ is a constant function, so does $f\circ g,$ which contradicts to the given data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes I think the question is a problematic too!